# Vagrant crashes (Encoding::CompatibilityError) when trying to mount NFS shared folders

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, nfs

I'm using Vagrant 1.3.4 on OS X 10.8.5 with VirtualBox and found it to be painfully slow.  Several sources suggested switching to NFS shares to improve performance, but when I add the `:nfs => true` bit in my `Vagrantfile`, I get the following fatal error during `vagrant up` (or `vagrant reload`):

```
[default] Exporting NFS shared folders...
Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
Password:
[default] Mounting NFS shared folders...
/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:284:in `block in write': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:284:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:284:in `write'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:322:in `block in write_string'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:319:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:319:in `write_string'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:55:in `block in from'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:47:in `step'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/buffer.rb:47:in `from'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:493:in `enqueue_pending_output'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:312:in `process'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `block in preprocess'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:217:in `preprocess'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:200:in `process'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:164:in `block in loop'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:164:in `loop'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:164:in `loop'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-2.6.8/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:369:in `shell_execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:64:in `block in execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:154:in `connect'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:63:in `execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:95:in `sudo'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/mount_nfs.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in mount_nfs_folder'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/retryable.rb:17:in `retryable'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/mount_nfs.rb:29:in `block in mount_nfs_folder'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/mount_nfs.rb:10:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/guests/linux/cap/mount_nfs.rb:10:in `mount_nfs_folder'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:139:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:139:in `capability'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/nfs.rb:93:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prune_nfs_exports.rb:15:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:118:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:54:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:19:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `block in run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:147:in `action'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:33:in `block in execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:185:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `each'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `with_target_vms'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:32:in `execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:478:in `cli'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.4/bin/vagrant:96:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
    from /Applications/Vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
```

Is there something I'm missing that should make this work?